# Buffering in pyQGIS? Task: Find all countries that are in the range of missiles

Tags: pyqgis

I am beginning user of pyQGIS and I have task to do. I need to find all cities outside country called **R**, which are in range of missiles based in city **K**. The range of missiles is 250 km. Missiles located 15 km inside the boundary of the city **K**.
I loaded Layers:

I. Cities:

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer("C:\cities.shp","miasta", "ogr")
layer.isValid()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

II. Countries:

```
layer2 = QgsVectorLayer("C:\country.shp","panstwa","ogr")
layer.isValid()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer2)
```

Then, I reaveled all cities outside R:

```
for f in layer.getFeatures():
geom = f.geometry()
if f['CNTRYNAME'] != 'R':
    print f['NAME']
```

And their coordinates:

```
for f in layer.getFeatures():
geom = f.geometry()
if f['CNTRYNAME'] != 'R':
    print geom.asPoint()
```

Now I don't know how to find out how many cities (except ones in R) are in the range of missiles.

How to create buffer which is 15 km from the border and how can i find all cities 250 km from that buffer? Maybe there is other way of doing that task?

I also have to find time that the missile travels from boarder of Kaliningrad to Lublin, Poland and ellipsoidal distance. Missile's speed = 2.5 Ma (850 m/s)
I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: So...you want help from the online community to identify which parts of the world can be blown up by these missiles? I think I'm going to flag this question.

Comment: Actually my professor seemed suspicious form the beggining, but i never tought he could be terrorist. ;)

Comment: Buffer the border by 235km (250-15) and select cities within that buffer

Comment: @user35594 Why do you think this is for people to have cities blown up, and not the reverse of identifying those that may be at risk?

Comment: @Joanna Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Have you tried anything for making your buffer?  Or selecting cities?  If so please [edit] your question to include this detail and the result.

Comment: Brain washing starts at school. What next? Where to place ship to kill as many North Koreans as possible. I see this question as a part of anti-Russian hysteria and vote to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is provocative.

Comment: @FelixIP
Honestely I haven't seen anything provocative in this question, it's just simple task from my university and I need to solve it. You can change missiles for planes if that bothers you. ;)

Comment: Have a look at first comment, if you think it is not. Changing to planes of bacteriological sprays will not help. It might work without names of cities and countries.

Comment: I think everyone in GIS has seen the Economist missile range map fail http://spatial.ly/2011/01/geographical-mistakes-keeping-geographers-busy/ ... so you could ask how to do it correctly and avoid this kind of embarrassment http://www.economist.com/node/1788311

Comment: @FelixIP Why do you think this is for people to have cities blown up, and not the reverse of identifying those that may be at risk?  Threat assessments are completed regularly by countries/cities around the world and I feel this question fits nicely into that category.  I don't see this as provocative at all, not in the content nor the wording.

Comment: @Midavalo yes I think the same. This is the question about people being at risk. What I don't like that it points at Russia as a source of that threat. This is why it is provocative. Our discussion also means that it is provocative.

Comment: @FelixIP OK that's a fair point.  Feel free to [edit] the question to remove/modify these references as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the reactions that this issue causes, the following code should do the trick (test in the python console):

```
selection = []    
for f in country.getFeatures(): #get the russian country
geom = f.geometry()
buffer = geom.buffer(235000,25) #buffer the russian country by 235 kms
diff_buffer = buffer.difference(geom) #create an hole to exclude russian country
for c in city.getFeatures(): # get the cities
    if c.geometry().intersects(diff_buffer): # perform the intersection
        selection.append(c.id()) # add the city which intersects to a list
city.setSelectedFeatures(selection) # select the cities which intersects
```

where country is your layer with russian country as a polygon and city is your layer containing your cities. Here I just select the matching cities but you can do what you want as they are stored in a list!